# HTML5 Video: How to Cover Controllers with a poster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I am using HTML5 to load a video from the backend. The UX requires a cover image that covers the whole HTML5 video player, including the controller. The issue is when I use the poster attribute to load a cover image, it does not cover the controller. Like their z-index is higher than the poster. Please see image below:

[image]

How can I have the poster image cover the controllers as well?

Comment: If it covered the controllers how would you use controllers then? Anyway you should use your own custom controllers

Comment: it covers them just initially before it plays. The moment I click on the cover, then the image/poster disappears and the controllers show again.

Comment: There's no way to force a browser player to behave like you said.

Comment: You could show an image and hide it when it's clicked and show the player

Comment: Yes I tried that but it looks a bit cheesy....

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple solution.

1) Remove *controls* attribute from video element

2) Show controls when video is clicked, like *onclick="this.controls = true"* or in event listener, e.g.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click', function(){
    video.controls = true;
}, false);
```

3) If you don't want to show controls when video is not loaded yet, you can check its *readyState* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState